# Is there a general way to determine whether the nth partial sum of a series has an explicit, closed-form representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The $n$th term $a_n$ of any series has a closed form representation if the nth partial sum $S_n$ has a explicit, closed-form representation; specifically, $a_n = S_{n+1}-S_n$

I'm interested in the converse situation. If the $n$th term of a series has an explicit, closed-form representation, is the $n$th partial sum guaranteed to have an explicit, closed-form representation? If so, is there a general way to determine this?

When I say explicit, closed-form representation, I am referring to a non-recursive, analytic expression whose number of terms is finite and does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. What would you use for the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) - the [$n$th partial sums of the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums)?

Comment: That seems like a great motivating example for this question! Can it be proven that such a representation does not exist for the harmonic numbers?

Comment: The harmonic numbers growth logarithmically, yet they are all rational. Can you think of a closed form that has both of these properties simultaneously?  (I can't.)

Comment: @Mithrandir I don't know about proving there is no such representation - but it's unlikely given the attention paid to these numbers for several centuries.

Comment: @EthanBolker The common denominator for the first n terms in the harmonic series is n!; and, since there are infinitely many primes, it makes sense that such a representation would not exist. I'm not sure how to make that rigorous though.